# Is there a base converter, for bases higher than 36, for PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, converters, radix

php only have 36 base converter, i need more than that, i found the code but it in js, can anyone help me translate it to php?

thanks.

```
    function baseConverter (number,ob,nb) {
        // Created 1997 by Brian Risk.  http://brianrisk.com
        //number = number.toUpperCase();
        var list = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var dec = 0;
        if(number=="0" || number=="" || number==0){
            number="0";
        }else{
            for (var i = 0; i <=  number.length; i++) {
                dec += (list.indexOf(number.charAt(i))) * (Math.pow(ob , (number.length - i - 1)));
            }
            number = "";
            var magnitude = Math.floor((Math.log(dec))/(Math.log(nb)));
            for (var i = magnitude; i >= 0; i--) {
                var amount = Math.floor(dec/Math.pow(nb,i));
                number = number + list.charAt(amount); 
                dec -= amount*(Math.pow(nb,i));
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Note, please read the FAQ. This question is not suited for StackOverflow. If you change the question to something alike "Is there a base converter, for bases higher than 36, for PHP?", you probably get better answers too.

Comment: If you're just looking for a base 64 encoder: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: @dtanders thanks for the link, but those base64 encoder make the string much longer, my program only processing base10 numbers encoded to custom base62, make it shorter for url and easier to process

Comment: @Pindatjuh hmn... its not just base converter i need those custom alphabeth too.. :D

Comment: I was actually trying to find a JS converter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 function baseConverter ($number,$ob,$nb) {
        $list = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $dec = 0;
        $number = (string)$number;
        if(empty($number)){
            $number="0";
        }
        else
        {
            $number_len  = strlen($number); 
            for ($i=0; $i<$number_len; $i++)
            {
                $dec += strpos($list, $number[$i])*(pow($ob, ($number_len-$i-1)));
            }
            $number = '';
            $magnitude = floor(log($dec)/log($nb));
            for($i=$magnitude; $i>=0; $i--)
            {
                $amount = floor($dec/pow($nb, $i));
                $number = $number.$list[$amount];
                $dec-= $amount*(pow($nb, $i));
            }
        }
        return $number;
     }

    var_dump( baseConverter("789", 10, 45));    

  will return string(2) "HO"
```